# Div на весь экран

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте.

Как сделать, чтобы размер дива был на весь экран? Сделал `width:100%` - не помогло.
http://jsfiddle.net/qjyLhnp6/

**Обновление**

Вот этот:

```
#ddmenu > li >ul
```

Comment: Какого дива-то? У вас их там несколько десятков и куча какого-то мусора. )

Comment: @inferusvv Обновил вопрос

Comment: @fikos, мне сложно понять ваш код, но как вариант могу предложить установить свойство `width` из скрипта. В нем уже будет известна ширина окна.

Comment: Чтобы вам помогли отформатируйте пример до читабельного состояния.

Answer (score 2):

Как Вы можете расширить `#ddmenu`, если он является дочерним к nav, который имеет фиксированную ширину в `970px`? По логике наследования, внутренние блоки не могут быть шире внешнего (если, конечно, не выставлен параметр `overflow:hidden`). Поэтому либо делайте родителей на весь экран и выстраивайте правильную логику наследования, либо я даже не знаю, как Вам помочь. Вы бы еще доходчиво объяснили, чего хотите добиться, может, я не правильно что-то понял.